# Hiding axes values in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to hide the `x,y` axes values as highlighted in the figure. Is it possible to do it? I also attach the expected representation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

n=3 
X = np.arange(n)
Y = -X

x_sorted = np.sort(X)
y_sorted = np.sort(Y)

ax.set_xticks(x_sorted)
ax.set_yticks(y_sorted)

ax.set_xlim(x_sorted[0], x_sorted[-1])
ax.set_ylim(y_sorted[0], y_sorted[-1])

ax.grid()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The expected representation is

[image]

Comment: Your expected result (image) is the same as the actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty `x` and `y` tick labels from `ax` variable:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])
```